# Creating a CanvasImageData object without an instance of canvas in JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm new to Javascript. I'm doing some image processing using canvas, and I'm trying to create a new CanvasImageData object without actually referencing a specific Canvas.

ie.

```
oImageData = CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData(vCSSWidth, vCSSHeight)
```

(from MSDN)

```
    // Why can't I write:
    var image_data = CanvasRenderingContext2D.createImageData(50, 50);
    // or:
    var image_data = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.createImageData(50, 50);
    // ?

    // Instead I must do:
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var image_data = canvas.createImageData(50, 50);
```

Is there a way to do this without an instance of Canvas? If not is there a reason why?

Thanks!

Comment: After thinking about this some more, the same origin policy doesn't really seem to be the culprit here. You can disregard my previous answer. :)

Comment: @Xenethyl I didn't think so. Thanks for considering the question though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly reference `createImageData` off of the interface prototype object:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.createImageData.call({ }, 100, 100); // ImageData
```

However, some environments (WebKit, for example) add restrictions on the type of object in context of which `createImageData` method (and likely others) is to be called:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.createImageData.call({ }, 100, 100); // TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

This works in at least Firefox nightly (just checked).

Reminds me of other WebKit's context restriction with `console.log`:

```
console.log.call({ }, 1); // TypeError: Illegal invocation
console.log.call(console, 1); // logs 1
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. I've been using Chrome. It works fine on firefox as CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.createImageData(50, 50) too.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

new ImageData(50, 50) works in Edge, Chrome, Opera, and Firefox now in 2023.

The ImageData constructor works in web workers but CanvasRenderingContext2D is not defined in workers.